# Variable scope error when attempting to JSON.stringify object after storing said object in Mongo DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, backend

Firstly, I would like to address my situation. I am attempting to build a to-do list webapp, in which I save my tasks in a MongoDB, so that I can pull the tasks from the MongoDB so that on the front end the task remains there permanently. The problem is, when I try to convert the object containing the task into a string, so that I can reference it in my client side JS, I get variable scope error (I am assuming) where the object is undefined, and thus I cannot res.end the data to my script.js file. Here is the code

```
app.get("/tasks", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query.task)
  res.send("hi " + req.query.task)
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err
    var dbo = db.db("Cluster0")
    
    var myobj = { task: req.query.task }
    
    dbo.collection("articles").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
     
      if (err) throw err
      console.log("1 document inserted")
      db.close();
      
    })
        var data = JSON.stringify(myobj)

    res.end(data);
    console.log(myobj)
    /*dbo.collection("articles").deleteMany({}, function(err, obj) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(obj.result.n + " document(s) deleted");
      db.close();
    });*/




  })
  
    
})
```

Here are my errors

```
ReferenceError: myobj is not defined
    at /home/runner/todolist/index.js:43:29
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/runner/todolist/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/runner/todolist/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/runner/todolist/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/runner/todolist/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/runner/todolist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/runner/todolist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/runner/todolist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/home/runner/todolist/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/runner/todolist/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
(node:7548) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
{ task: 'sadsda', _id: 5efbe175fef3df1d7c5135ce }
1 document inserted

```

As you can see, I can indeed console.log(myobj), so I am not sure why it is not able to be converted with JSON.stringify. On a side note, if I am able to successfully parse the object into my client side JS file, will the information stay their permanently, or will it be gone if I refresh the webpage? Any ideas on how I can directly take out data from my MongoDB and store the info in my client side JS so that I can display the To-do tasks permanently?
I hope I am making myself specific.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert `myobj`, make sure you also then return it, send to client once successfuly saved and then display it however you want:

```
db.collection('articles').insertOne(myobj, function (error, response) {
    if(error) {
        console.log('Error occurred while inserting');
    } else {
       console.log('inserted record', response.ops[0]);
       //send if saved obj is returned
       res.send(response.ops[0])
    }
});
```

---

The information will be always refreshed on a client-side (page refresh). You will need to make the call again to grab relevant information from the database. Of course, you could try to save some information in `cookies` but that would be an overkill in this case.

In general, it would be ok to do one request to get the list each time client visits the page.

---

You only use `myobj` to save it to your database. After that, you should work with the response from the `insertOne` - newly saved document.

It might be the case that saving the data to the database was not successful - in that case, you do not want to send the object anyway (will be misleading).

For your [reference](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#insert-a-document) -
*ops Contains the documents inserted with added _id fields*

`response.ops` is going to be an array so we need to access the first element of it at an index of 0 - `[0]`

I do not think you necessarily need to use `JSON.stringify` on the backend in this case. See what works best for you.

Comment: I am having trouble what response.ops is in this situation. Can you clarify on that for me? Furthermore, why are you indexing the 0th element of it? Finally, do I not have to json.strinfgify the object? How come myobj isn't included in the else code?